# Как по значению тега обновить другой тег?

Tags: c#, xml

Есть xml:

```
<JOBS>
 <job ID="1" CheckForScan="True" JobName="new job (1)" Information="" PathToInputFolder="D:\test\input" PathToOutputFolder="D:\test\output" PathToErrorsFolder="D:\test\error" ParseSubfolders="False" UseFilter="True" Filter="*.txt" KindOfSort="Without sorting" Ascending="False" UseTemplateForTheFileName="True" TemplateForTheFileName="%ORIGNAME%.%ORIGEXT%7" UseArchiveFolder="True" PathToArchiveFolder="D:\test\archive" ScanInterval="True" TimeInterval="1" ScanDate="16.08.2017 10:16:16" Daily="False" KindOfScan="" NextScan="" PreviousScan="" /> 
 <job ID="2" CheckForScan="True" JobName="new job (2)" Information="" PathToInputFolder="D:\test\input" PathToOutputFolder="D:\test\output" PathToErrorsFolder="" ParseSubfolders="True" UseFilter="True" Filter="*.AVI" KindOfSort="Without sorting" Ascending="False" UseTemplateForTheFileName="False" TemplateForTheFileName="" UseArchiveFolder="True" PathToArchiveFolder="D:\test\archive" ScanInterval="False" TimeInterval="1" ScanDate="16.08.2017 14:07:03" Daily="True" KindOfScan="" NextScan="" PreviousScan="" /> 
 <settings MaxThreads="5" EndPosition="0" MaxAttempts="" WaitingTime="" /> 
 </JOBS>
```

Именно в узле job нужно обновить значение тега Information по Id. Как это можно сделать?

Comment: 1. Десериализация. 2. Любые действия. 3. Сериализация. Работайте с объектами, это удобно и безопасно в отношении типов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например так:
Загрузите любым способом свой xml в XDocument:

```
XDocument xdoc = ...;
```

И установите значение атрибута для каждого элемента в цикле:

```
foreach (var e in xdoc.Root.Elements("job"))
    e.Attribute("Information").SetValue(e.Attribute("ID").Value);
```